# Centering a section using margin auto not working

Tags: html, css

I have 3 sections, 1 is float left and the second is float right on same line.  I want the third section block centered below the other 2.  I can float it either left or right and add a bunch of margin to the opposite side and it works, but there must be a more efficient way.  margin:auto for left and right sticks it to the right side.  Any suggestions on why this will not center?  Thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/tkennedy/69rj6d7f/

```
#interests {
width: 90%;
border: thin solid #000000;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
clear: right;
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're inheriting `float:right` from `section` rule.

Override with `float:none`.

```
#interests {
width: 90%;
border: thin solid #000000;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
clear: right;
float:none;
}
```

Comment: @tkennedy: Make sure you place this AFTER your "section" CSS.

Comment: grr you are faster ;)

Comment: @AndyW Doesn't matter where it's placed due to CSS precedence. http://www.alternategateways.com/tutorials/css/css-101/part-four-the-css-order-of-precedence . ID > attribute.